# Python keras: to_categorical for multilabel values gives ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, valueerror

I have a training set `y_train`( which has 8 unique classes) derived using `train_test_split` on my dataset.

> y_train

```
    2019       AD
    777     QUERY
    282      INFO
    1879     REAL
    910     QUERY
        ...  
    997     QUERY
    510      FAKE
    252      REAL
    1334     FAKE
    1579     INFO
    Name: target, Length: 1653, dtype: object
```

Now when I run `to_categorical` on this set I get this error.

> y_train = to_categorical(np.asarray(y_train),8, dtype='O')

```
     41     """
     42 
---> 43     y = np.array(y, dtype='int')
     44     input_shape = y.shape
     45     if input_shape and input_shape[-1] == 1 and len(input_shape) > 1:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'AD'
```

I have also tried the  `y_train = to_categorical(np.asarray(y_train))` but it gives the same error, which I cannot figure out why? The dtype is 'object' of my training set and I am setting it as dtype = 'O' so what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 5):

This worked.

> y_train = to_categorical(np.asarray(y_train.factorize()[0]))

The `factorize()` method encodes each string to a categorical value because `to_categorical` can only take `dtpye` of `int` or `float`

Comment: Could you explain what it does?